# How to await multiple possibly uninitialized Tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have an API POST endpoint creating a resource, that resource may have multiple relationships. To make sure the resource is created with valid relationships first I need to check if the given IDs exist. There are multiple such relations, and I don't want to await each sequentially. Here's my code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Person>> PostPerson(Person person)
{
    ValueTask<Person> master, apprentice;
    ValueTask<Planet> planet;
    ValueTask<Models.LifeFormType> lifeFormType;
    if (person.MasterId.HasValue)
    {
        master = _context.People.FindAsync(person.MasterId);
    }
    

    if (person.ApprenticeId.HasValue)
    {
        apprentice = _context.People.FindAsync(person.ApprenticeId);
    }

    if (person.FromPlanetId.HasValue)
    {
        planet = _context.Planets.FindAsync(person.FromPlanetId);
    }

    if (person.LFTypeId.HasValue)
    {
        lifeFormType = _context.LifeFormTypes.FindAsync(person.LFTypeId);
    }
    List<ValueTask> tasks = new List<ValueTask> {master, apprentice, planet, lifeFormType};

    // if the above worked I'd process the tasks as they completed and throw errors
    // if the given id was not found and such
    
    _context.Attach(person);
    // _context.People.Add(person);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetPerson", new { id = person.Id }, person);
}
```

As shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete) I want to await the list of `[master,apprentice,planet,lifeFormType]` as they complete, but I get an error during the creation of the list that `Local variable 'master' might not be initialized before accessing`. So I tried in each check if the resource has that value to create an `else` block and somehow add a `ValueTask.CompletedTask` like so:

```cs
if (person.MasterId.HasValue)
{
    master = _context.People.FindAsync(person.MasterId);
}
else
{
    master = ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}
```

but then I get an error saying that `Cannot convert source type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask' to target type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<Models.Person>'`.

How to do this? I guess I'll just await each and every request for now.

Comment: `ValueTask<Person> master = default;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid this by initializing `master` at the declaration site.

The easiest way is using the `default` keyword.

```
ValueTask<Person> master = default;
```

Comment: This solves the first error, but how to go about sticking the `ValueTask<Person>` and `ValueTask<Planet>` into a single list, because I'm getting `Argument type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<Models.Person>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask'` with `var tasks = new List<ValueTask> {master, apprentice, planet, lifeFormType};`

Comment: @koral I see. `ValueTask` represents an asynchronous operation that does not produce a result. This is in contrast to `ValueTask<T>` which produces a result of type `T`. Something like `List<ValueTask<LeastCommonType>>` is what you want, but you may want to refactor a bit.

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(master.AsTask(), apprentice.AsTask(), planet.AsTask(), lifeFormType.AsTask());` this finally worked.